# How does the DNS protocol switch from UDP to TCP?

Tags: domain-name-system, rfc

Before anyone asks: I've seen [When do DNS queries use TCP instead of UDP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/404840/when-do-dns-queries-use-tcp-instead-of-udp) and it doesn't answer my question.

All I keep hearing is "*if the answer is too long, DNS will use TCP*". This does not explain how it happens though.

So here's the situation: DNS client asks for resolution of a record using UDP. The record is too long for UDP:

1. server answers with specific opcode, to have client switch to TCP
2. server doesn't answer at all, and client re-tries over TCP
3. server opens TCP connection to client (stupid, if you count NAT, but who knows?)
4. client somehow (?) 'knows' that given query should be run over TCP so it doesn't bother with UDP in the first place
5. DNS pixies magically turn UDP into TCP when needed

I've been looking all over the internet for the answer, but there's lot of noise (see above), and I can't seem to write proper Google query for that (nor can I find the info in RFCs, for that matter).

Comment: All I could find was in RFC5966: "A resolver SHOULD send a UDP
   query first, but MAY elect to send a TCP query instead if it has good
   reason to expect the response would be truncated if it were sent over
   UDP (with or without EDNS0) or for other operational reasons, in
   particular, if it already has an open TCP connection to the server.". When should resolver "expect" that the response will be truncated?

Comment: An obvious example would be if a previous request for the same record was too long to fit in a UDP datagram.

Comment: So there's an opcode that says 'truncated', right? And it switches then - basically what I thought, it's the most obvious solution.

Comment: Case (d) may be a wise choice if the query contains multiple "questions" (addresses to resolve). If you need to resolve 100 addresses, you're not going to be able to fit the response in a single UDP packet.

Comment: `1.` and `4.` are both roughly correct (which of the two depends on circumstances).

Comment: BTW. Saying `3.` would be stupid because of NAT is not actually a valid argument because NAT did not exist when DNS was designed. If DNS had been done like your option `3.`, then it would have been stupid to make a NAT which could not handle that. But you could argue that `3.` is problematic because it would require every DNS client to bind to a TCP port before sending any requests and somehow communicate to the DNS server where it is listening.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The client does not know in advance that the response will be too large, so it will query the server via UDP.
The server will respond via UDP and will include as much as possible and set the truncated header bit ("TC" http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/dns.htm).
The client can then resend the request via TCP and get the full response.

See also: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5966

> In the absence of EDNS0 (Extension Mechanisms for DNS 0) (see
> below),    the normal behaviour of any DNS server needing to send a
> UDP response    that would exceed the 512-byte limit is for the server
> to truncate    the response so that it fits within that limit and then
> set the TC    flag in the response header.  When the client receives
> such a    response, it takes the TC flag as an indication that it
> should retry    over TCP instead.

And: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2181.txt

And as mentioned in the comments, of course DNS zone transfers are always using TCP.

Comment: RFC 5966 also notes that TCP is *always* used for zone transfers.

Comment: @MattNordhoff Right, that's true and good to mention. This was more aimed at the 'how does the switch from UDP to TCP work?' angle. But I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: However if there is already a TCP connection it will only use TCP

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. So when does it fall back to UDP?

Comment: @JimB Are you sure about that? I don't think it keeps a persistent TCP connection open.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't say it kept a persistent connectionbut if one is open it will use that rather than start all over again