# how are DNS queries processed in Linux?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm trying to understand how are the DNS queries done in Linux.

I understand the programs can check first `/etc/hosts` for an IP attached to the name and then `/etc/resolv.conf` for the DNS server.

So how does it work for a browser?
When I type `http://www.google.fr` what does the browser do first?
Does it check only those files and send the query to the DNS server if there is nothing in `/etc/hosts`?
How is the query sent (there are several RFC's  and protocols on the [Wikipedia article of DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)) : which port and protocol??

Now how does it work for OpenVPN?

If I use a program like `curl` or `firefox` with OpenVPN activated, does it send the DNS query through the tunnel or independently?
Which port and protocol does it use?
With my basic understanding, I would guess OpenVPN rearrange iptables and sends queries using iptables rules through the tunnel. So it would depend on the protocols used by the program sending the DNS queries.  Am I right?

Comment: Generic Linux questions are better asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ and try to ask questions that are focussed and can be answered in  few paragraphs without copying the full Wikipedia article, please read that there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Comment: The browser doesn't even know a hosts file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It depends

Applications might do their own thing, independent of what the OS is configured to do.

For example after setting a custom secure DNS provider in the “Settings > Privacy & Security > Security” in the Chrome webbrowser the system resolver is no longer used.

### System resolver

When the application does *not* do it's own thing, the application typically calls on the system resolver by using OS/kernel functions such as the legacy [`gethostbyname()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html) and/or the more modern [`getaddrinfo()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) to translate the hostname or fully qualified domain name (FQDN) to an IPv4/IPv6 address.

The Name Service Switch (NSS) configuration file, [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf), is used to configure the sources from which to obtain name-service information and in what order.

That `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is for example where  the usual default order  of `/etc/hosts` (the *"files"* keyword) getting consulted before DNS is configured with:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

hosts:          files dns
```

When the hostname can't be found in the  hosts files, then fallback to the DNS resolver is used.

The DNS resolver is configured with [`/etc/resolv.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolver).

Classically that file contains a list of name servers (with the first `nameserver` getting used as the default nameserver and any additional ones only getting used when the ones before do not respond):

```
# /etc/resolv.conf file 

domain           example.com
search           int.example.com ad.example.com 
nameserver       8.8.8.8
nameserver       1.1.1.1
```

but in modern Linux distributions you'll typically see that the systemd resolver gets configured there. That has some advanced and interesting features which I won't explain here:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

### VPN

AFAIK usually  VPN software has a feature that changes the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` for the duration of the connection to the VPN server, when configured to do so.
See for example: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Pushing-DNS-to-clients

Nothing fancy needed with iptables, changing resolv.conf immediately adjusts how your whole system does DNS resolution.

### DNS protocols

DNS queries always use UDP and port 53, *except when they don't.*
See [How does the DNS protocol switch from UDP to TCP?](https://serverfault.com/q/698251/984089)

I ***think*** that using something other than classical DNS queries over UDP requires either using the more advanced systemd resolvd, (which [supports](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/DNS_Over_TLS)  for example DNS over TLS,)  as a resolver rather than relying the classic C libraries.

Alternatively, similar to how PAM is designed, Name Service Switch (NSS) is designed to add new modules without changing any of the programs and code that call on the system resolver. Add an additional resolver library to support a different DNS protocol and adjust `nsswitch.conf` to use that library, see for example https://github.com/dimkr/nss-tls

Comment: thanks for your time! that explains the linux part. now a dns query can be done through udp:53,tcp:53, or https or tls (see different rfc). do you know where is that configured?

Comment: Added a section **DNS protocols** to my answer