# Do I need to open any port for NTP synchronization to work if both outgoing and incoming are blocked on ufw?

Tags: firewall, linux-networking, ufw

One of my production servers, **UFW** configuration is as follows:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), **deny (outgoing)**, disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (uv6)
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I've enabled NTP synchronisation by installing ntp service and it's currently running. When I run `ntpq -p`, I get following output:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+209.114.111.1   132.163.4.103    2 u  52m 1024  374   44.591    3.390   0.983
+208.75.89.4     216.218.192.202  2 u  51m 1024  374   67.622    2.429   2.171
*204.9.54.119    .CDMA.           1 u  40m 1024  374   24.324    2.344   2.116
-72.14.183.239   200.98.196.212   2 u  41m 1024  374   41.822    4.611   2.649
-91.189.94.4     193.79.237.14    2 u  43m 1024  374   74.764   -0.407   3.417
```

From the above output, apparently it looks like **ntp** is already working properly without opening any additional port on **ufw**-firewall. Is this understanding correct *OR* do I need to open any port for NTP synchronization to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Your 'when' column is telling me that ntp last chatted with those servers at best 40 minutes ago, yet your poll interval is 1024 seconds (~17 minutes).  ntp does not seem to be running properly, which makes sense given your firewall configuration.

You'll need an outbound and an inbound allow rule for UDP 123.  The inbound is needed since UDP is stateless. It's like receiving mail from someone you don't know.

Comment: Thank you Neil.
Additionally I've opened TCP **53** for outgoing traffic to DNS work since _/etc/ntp.conf_ contains ntp servers' names not IP addresses. It's now working properly.

Comment: That's a good catch - I didn't even think of DNS!  However, DNS also uses UDP for most transactions: http://serverfault.com/questions/404840/when-do-dns-queries-use-tcp-instead-of-udp

But, feel free to verify this before taking firewall advice from an internet stranger: Make sure you're logging blocked connections, or at least blocked connections on 53 tcp & udp.  Run a few dns queries (ping works fine for this), and check the log.

Just set up your DNS rule similar to the NTP rule: 53 UDP inbound & outbound.  Leave your 53 TCP in place also.